# Regex with multiple negative conditions

Tags: regex

I'm trying to do a regex to fill the following conditions :

1- string must be 8 characters long

2- All characters must be numbers

3- Any number must not be repeated 8 times
(ie: 11111111, 22222222 are forbidden)

4- 1 to 8 suite is forbidden
(ie: 12345678)

5- 8 to 1 suite is forbidden
(ie: 87654321 is not allowed)

So far I'm having this regex for points 1,2 & 3:

```
^(?=.{8})(\d)(?!\1{7})\d{7}$
```

And this one for points 4 & 5:

```
^(?!(12345678$|87654321$))
```

But I can't combine them both in one longer regex. That's why I came here for help before my brain explodes.
Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
^(?!(\d)\1{7})(?!12345678|87654321)\d{8}$
```

Try this.See demo.

http://regex101.com/r/dZ1vT6/29

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help to all of you guys.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this pattern:

```
^(?=[0-9]{8}$)(?!12345678|87654321).*?(.)(?!\1).+
```

an other way (if supported):

```
^(?=[0-9]{8}$)(.)\1*+.++(?<!12345678|87654321)
```

the idea behind this second pattern is to sort the conditions from the most restrictive/probable to the less restrictive/probable.

The regex engine needs to support possessive quantifiers and lookbehind for this second pattern.

Answer (score 1):

This one should suit your needs:

```
^(?!(\d)\1+$)(?!12345678$|87654321$)\d{8}$
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/BilsAS5kAHcskCZ7)

Comment: This website is definitely going into my favorites. Thanks for sharing.

Answer (score 1):

This is another way

```
 # ^(?=\d{8}$)(?!(\d)\1{7}|12345678|87654321).*$

 ^ 
 (?= \d{8} $ )
 (?!
      ( \d )            # (1)
      \1{7} 
   |  12345678
   |  87654321
 )
 .* 
 $
```